# Group results based on value of child element

Tags: php, xml, domdocument

HI i have folder full of images which are been read as xml file.
I want to group them by child element which is date.

Images format:

```
entry_212_CA60CTF_2014-10-30_12-14-57.jpg
```

XML doc:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Incidents xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Count="3" Date="2014-10-30" Time="12:14:57" FileName="2014-10-30_dones_Hillsborough_Leisure_Centre.xml">
  <Incident>
    <EntryTime>2014-08-16T08:54:12</EntryTime>// want to group by this element
    <ExitTime>2014-08-16T17:03:51</ExitTime>
 </Incident>
```

PHP FILE:

```
    if(file_exists($xmlFullFilename)) {
            $xmlDoc = new DomDocument();
            $xmlDoc->load($xmlFullFilename);
            $tmp = $xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName("Incidents");
            $root = $tmp->item(0);
}
```

I want to group all the EntryTime of same date into one xml file. the xml file should contain only 16th date.

```
eg:<EntryTime>2014-08-16T08:46:17</EntryTime>...

          $tmp = split(" ", $entryTime);
                $dateString = $tmp[0] . "T" . $tmp[1];
                $entryTimeNode = $xmlDoc->createElement("EntryTime", $dateString);
```

Answer (score 0):

I presume that you want to be able to get the information for any date, not just August 16th, so here is some more generic code that will do that for you. You can use [DOMXPath](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) to extract all the date/time combinations from the file, create an array with the different dates in it, and then get all the incidents that occur on that date. Here is some sample code:

```
$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->loadXML( get_xml() );

$xp = new DOMXPath( $dom );

$d_list = array();

# get all EntryTime nodes in the document
foreach ($xp->query("Incident/EntryTime") as $x) {
    # take a substring of the nodeValue corresponding to the date, put it in an array
    # nodeValue is in the form YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS so we just need the YYYY-MM-DD part
    $d_list[ substr( $x->nodeValue, 0, 10 ) ] = 1;
}

# $d_list now contains every date referenced in the file
# if you only want the Incidents for a certain date, you obviously don't need to use
# use a foreach loop!
foreach ($d_list as $d => $v) {
    # select every EntryTime node where the value starts with $d
    # the /.. at the end returns its parent node, i.e. the Incident node
    foreach ($xp->query("Incident/EntryTime[starts-with(.,'$d')]/..") as $node) {
        # now do whatever you want with the Incident node data
        print_r($node);

    }
}
```